# How to CONCATENATE values from different cells? (No.of cells may vary every time)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Words & meanings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq6MJ.png)

I wanna combine the data as shown in the picture as below for every word:

**Please click on the above "words & meanings" link to see the image**

> [{"txt":"A cleric's house and land, especially the residence of a Presbyterian minister.","pos":"noun"},{"txt":"A large stately
>   residence.","pos":"noun"},{"txt":"Archaic   The dwellings belonging to
>   a householder.","pos":"noun"}],

For every word, there are a different number of meanings so the number of cells to combine are not constant. How to combine these in excel?

Please help me out with some formula.

Comment: You would be better off with a proper JSON parser.

Comment: That's JSON data; you'll probably have more luck fitting it with your excel knowledge of you tabularise it first. See something like https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/980302-parse-json-values-excel-cells.html or https://sunlightfoundation.com/2014/03/11/making-json-as-simple-as-a-spreadsheet/ or https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-access-a-json-api-with-power-query/ - suggestions from web search "working with JSON in excel"

Comment: Thanks for your response.
In my data, no.of cells to concatenate are not constant. To use the above formula I have to define cell range for every word. There are more than five thousand words like that. I need a formula which I can drag down to to combine meanings of a word. Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? @Kalyani

Comment: @JvdV I am using 2013 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data starts from A1 with no headings, place this formula in C1 and fill down:

```
=IF(A2="",B1&C2,B1)
```

The rows with values in column A will have the full joined text in column C.

Comment: In my data, no.of cells to concatenate are not constant. To use the above formula I have to define cell range for every word. There are more than five thousand words like that. I need a formula which I can drag down to to combine meanings of a word. Thanks in advance

Comment: I understand your question. You do not change the formula based on the number of words. Just copy the formula exactly as it is and fill down.

Comment: Yes I did but I am not getting the expected result, Thanks

Comment: @Kalyani so what do you think is incorrect and how would you edit the function to sort that?

Comment: For the example you gave, it gives you exactly what you asked for. What result are you getting and how is it different to what you asked for? Remember, it is only on the rows with words that you get the full definition. The other rows in between just build up the full string you asked for piece by piece. The row with the word is the full result.

Comment: Please dont consider it as JSON data. They gave multiple meanings for every word  and I have to combine all meanings of a word into one cell. 


=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(B1:B3))

I used this formula first to combine but  for every word I have to edit cell range so I wanna check whether I can do it with any formula so that I can drag down for all words

Thanks!

Comment: I am not considering it as JSON data. I understand your question. I have given you a formula that when filled down, joins together all definitions for the word, regardless of how many definitions there are. Use the formula I gave. Do not change it. Fill it down entirely. If it is not giving you what you want, then you need to explain why not. On the rows with a word, the formula gives all definitions joined together exactly as you said you wanted in the question. Make sure your data is set up the way I said in my answer. If your data starts elsewhere, tell me where.

Comment: @ Michael Ok, I used the same formula as u said. I couldn't upload image in comments so I m giving you image link to check the result if i apply the formula given by u as it is 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wP5PTvJX0YB4tgU3pNjOMLFuXN_QP1E9

But I need result like this ::

[{"txt":"A cleric's house and land, especially the residence of a Presbyterian minister.","pos":"noun"},{"txt":"A large stately residence.","pos":"noun"},{"txt":"Archaic The dwellings belonging to a householder.","pos":"noun"}],

Please correct me If I did any mistakes

Comment: You haven't filled the formula down. You need to fill the formula down to the bottom of your data. The value against the first row isn't correct until you fill it down.

Comment: @Michael Hey, I got it now. thank you so much. Sorry for troubling you. 
This is what you mean right?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11WrJK8vVyVljOA3mHoCje0I-xOBTdrzO

The cells marked in green is the result. I got the result but I didnt get logic behind your formula that's why I got confused

Comment: Yes that's correct. The green cells are the only cells you want, but the other cells are required to build up the result in the green cells. The formula works from the bottom up, adding to the list of definitions with each row, but starts again for each new word. If this solves your problem, don't forget to mark this answer as correct using the tick next to it.

Comment: Thanks. Next time just be mindful to follow all instructions before saying something isn't working. I said 5 times that you needed to fill the formula down.